# ConvertTo-PnPClientSidePage change default list to search in

Tags: powershell

My question is, are you able to change the default list that the cmdlet searches?  Currently your site has to be in the "Site Pages" page library.  However the SharePoint admin before me liked to put all sites under a new list/folder called sites and not keep them in "Site Pages".

Answer (score 0):

by Site do You mean a Page?

If You want to use ConvertTo-PnPClientSidePage on a Page that is in some different location You may use the -Library parameter in which You specify the location of the page. You may also use -Folder if this page is in some folder of this library.

for Your case the command may look something like (this converts a web part page named 'somepage' living inside the Sites library ):

```
ConvertTo-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "somepage.aspx" -Library "Sites" -Overwrite
```

According to the description of this parameter:

```
-Library
The name of the library containing the page. If SitePages then please omit this parameter
```

please verify the full description of the command -> [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/convertto-pnpclientsidepage?view=sharepoint-ps)